# How to restrict a class __init__ argument to be a list of another class?

Tags: python, oop

I have these four classes.

```
class Button(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def invoke(self):
    return self.button_dict


class Template(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def message(self):
    message = {'attachment': { 'type': self.type }}
    message['attachment'].update(self.payload)

    return message


class URLButton(Button):
  def __init__(self, title, url):
    self.button_dict = {
      'type': 'web_url',
      'title': title,
      'url': url
    }


class ButtonTemplate(Template):
  def __init__(self, title, buttons):
    if (not all(isinstance(button, Button) for button in buttons)):
      raise ValueError('Invalid Buttons instances.')

    self.type = 'button'
    self.payload = {
      'title': title,
      'buttons': [
        button.invoke() for button in buttons
      ]
    }
```

Calling...

```
ButtonList = [
  URLButton('Test URL 1', 'http://example.com'),
  URLButton('Test URL 2', 'http://example.com'),
  'Invalid button here'
]

print(ButtonTemplate('Test', ButtonList).message())
```

I have a lot of classes expecting a list of *Button* instances and I want to avoid this validation below in all my classes:

```
if (not all(isinstance(button, Button) for button in buttons)):
    raise ValueError('Invalid Buttons instances.')
```

Is there a way to force an argument to be a **list of instances**?
What's the better way to restrict an argument?

**Working snippet: https://repl.it/NJUv/2**

Comment: You can introduce type hints and check them with something like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). Since you’re calling `.invoke()` immediately, you can also just skip checking and rely on duck typing.

Comment: @Ryan Type hints is a great method to run with tests. I'm building a Python module so I need to raise an error if an user tries to pass an invalid list (in this case) of invalid instances. I don't think I can do it using type hints... Can I? :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a better way to do this other than what you have. However, you can use a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) so the instance checking logic is decoupled from the actual business logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut-down on the boiler-plate code a bit by using a decorator to modify each class' `__init__()` method:

```
from functools import wraps

def validate_buttons_arg(func):
  """ Method decorator that makes sure buttons argument is a list of Button
      instances.
  """
  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(self, title, buttons, *args, **kwargs):
    if (not all(isinstance(button, Button) for button in buttons)):
      raise ValueError('Invalid Buttons instances.')
    return func(self, title, buttons, *args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper


class ButtonTemplate(Template):
  @validate_buttons_arg  # Sample usage.
  def __init__(self, title, buttons):
    self.type = 'button'
    self.payload = {
      'title': title,
      'buttons': [
        button.invoke() for button in buttons
      ]
    }
```

It would also be possible to use a class decorator or metaclass to do something similar automatically to the `__init__()` method of each class to which they were applied (instead of manually adding a `@validate_button_arg` line before their `def __init__`s).

Comment: Just thought of another idea. Create a base class that all `Button` classes derive from and put the validation code in _its_ `__init__()` method. Then call `super().__init__(<args>)` at the beginning of each derived class' `__init__()` method (Python doesn't do that automatically like, say, C++ classes do). This would probably be considered the more object-oriented way of accomplishing things, if that matters...